# Ansible search string in stdout_lines and user later as variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I Have below ansible output in stdout_lines

```
    "test.stdout_lines": [
        "Get VM Power State Script",
        "Loading vmware.vimautomation.core",
        "",
        "Attempting to connect to server1. Please wait.",
        "",
        "Connected to server1",
        "\tGathering VM Info...",
        "",
        "Attempting to connect to serevr2. Please wait.",
        "",
        "Connected to server2.",
        "\tGathering VM Info...",
        "File Exported to D:\\Scripts\\Exports\\VM_State_201907151824.csv . Please verify the content",
        "",
        "Complete."
```

I want to store the file location in last line of the output as variable,i.e., location:- D:\Scripts\Exports\VM_State_201907151824.csv. How can it be done?

Comment: What generates that output in the first place?

Comment: Are the hosts, windows are linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
{{ test.stdout_lines | join(' ') | regex_replace( '^.*File Exported to (.*) \. Please .*$', '\\1') }}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks fo rreplying, no its not working, getting this :- "test2": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" 
I used this:-
test2 = "{{ test.stdout_lines | join(' ') | regex_replace( '^.*File Exported to (.*) \. Please .*$', '\\1') }}"

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
- name: Get the file_path
  set_fact:
    file_path: "{{ test.stdout_lines | select('match', 'File Exported to.+') | list | regex_replace( '^.*File Exported to (.*) \\. Please .*$', '\\1') }}"
- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ file_path }}"
```